# Add Element while Zooming d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have to achieve a zoom functionality which will add child nodes and remove child node while zoom in and out.
[image]

I can achieve it but While Panning or dragging it again calling zoom event which is doing Adding and removing child node to it.

Please check my code to see what I achieved till now.

```js
 var graph = {
       "nodes": [
       {
           "x": 30,
           "y": 30,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Start",
           display: "none",
           tx: -5,
           ty: -15
       },
       {
           "x": 300,
           "y": 30,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 1"
       },
       {
           "x": 700,
           "y": 30,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 2"
       },
       {
           "x": 1000,
           "y": 30,
           fixed: true,
           display: "none",
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 1000,
           "y": 200,
           fixed: true,
           display: "none",
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 500,
           "y": 200,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 3"
       },
       {
           "x": 60,
           "y": 200,
           display: "none",
           fixed: true,
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 60,
           "y": 400,
           fixed: true,
           display: "none",
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 300,
           "y": 400,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 4"
       },
       {
           "x": 700,
           "y": 400,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 5"
       },
       {
           "x": 1000,
           "y": 400,
           fixed: true,
           display: "none",
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 1000,
           "y": 600,
           fixed: true,
           display: "none",
           name: ""
       },
       {
           "x": 500,
           "y": 600,
           fixed: true,
           name: "Module 6"
       },
       {
           "x": 30,
           "y": 600,
           fixed: true,
           name: "END",
           display: "none",
           tx: -10,
           ty: -20
       }
        ],
           "links": [
           {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 3
        },
        {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 4
        },
        {
            "source": 4,
            "target": 5
        } ,
        {
            "source": 5,
            "target": 6
        } ,
        {
            "source": 6,
            "target": 7
        },
        {
            "source": 7,
            "target": 8
        } ,
        {
            "source": 8,
            "target": 9
        } ,
        {
            "source": 9,
            "target": 10
        } ,
        {
            "source": 10,
            "target": 11
        },
        {
            "source": 11,
            "target": 12
        },
        {
            "source": 12,
            "target": 13
        } ,
        {
            "source": 13,
            "target": 0
        }     
       ]
   }

   var width = 1200,
       height = 900;

  
   

   var container, zoomscale = 1;
   update(graph);
   function update(graph){


     var force = d3.layout.force()
       .size([width, height])
       .on("tick", tick);
   
   var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
       .scaleExtent([1, 4])
       .on("zoom", zoomed);

   var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
       .origin(function(d) { return d; })
       .on("dragstart",function() { d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); })
       .on("drag", dragged)
       .on("dragend", dragended);

   var svg = d3.select("#zoomModuleView").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")


    container = svg.append("g");
   var link = container.selectAll(".link"),
       node = container.selectAll(".node");
   var gnodes;
   
    force.nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .alpha(0.01)
        .start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    

     gnodes = container.selectAll('g.gnode')
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('gnode', true)
      

    node = gnodes.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr('x',function(d){ if (d.tx) {return d.tx} else {return -25}})
        .attr('y',function(d){ if (d.ty) {return d.ty} else {return -30}})
        .attr("width", 180)
        .attr('height',80 )
        .style("display", function (d) {
         return d.display;
     })
     .style('fill', '#F2F3F4')

     
        
    var labels = gnodes.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ if (d.tx) {return d.tx} else {return 30}})
      .attr("y", function(d){ if (d.ty) {return d.ty} else {return 35}})
      .text(function(d) {  
       if(d.name !="Start"&&d.name !="END")
        return d.name; 
      });

    var image_node = gnodes.append("svg:image")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr('x',function(d){ if (d.tx) {return d.tx} else {return 40}})
        .attr('y',function(d){ if (d.ty) {return d.ty} else {return -15}})
        .attr("width", 36)
        .attr('height',36)
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
         if(d.name !="Start"&&d.name !="END"){
          return "D:/Chandan/New%20Proj/Mock%20Up/Book1.png"
         }else{
          return "D:/Chandan/New%20Proj/Mock%20Up/Book2.png"
         }
        })
        .style("display", function (d) {
         if(d.name !="Start"&&d.name !="END")
          return d.display;
     })

     function tick() {
              link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                  return d.source.x;
              })
                  .attr("y1", function (d) {
                  return d.source.y;
              })
                  .attr("x2", function (d) {
                  return d.target.x;
              })
                  .attr("y2", function (d) {
                  return d.target.y;
              });

              gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
              return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
            });
          }
   }
   

   
   function zoomed() {
    
    
       container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
      

 
   }
   function dragstarted(d) {
   
     d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
     d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
   }

   function dragged(d) {
    console.log(d);
      
     d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
    
   }

   function dragended(d) {
    console.log(d);
     d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
   }
   $(".link").last().attr("style","stroke-dasharray: 10px")
```

```css
.link {
      stroke: #0FB2EF;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  .node {

      fill: #FFFFFF;
      stroke: #E4F4F8;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  text{
   fill: burlywood;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id ="zoomModuleView" style="margin-left: 140px;"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't make **Everything** bold and capitalized.

Comment: @KasperSouren Ok thanks for suggestion .